# Python 3 ~ How to take rows from a csv file and put them into a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, names

I would like to know how to take this file:

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
Charlie,3,2,5
```

and put it in a list like the following:

```
[['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [2, 8, 3], [4, 1, 5], [3, 2, 5]]
```

I'm fairly new to python so excuse me
my current code looks like this:

```
file = open(argv[1] , "r")
file1 = open(argv[2] , "r")

text = file1.read()

strl = []


with file:

    csv = csv.reader(file,delimiter=",")

    for row in csv:
        strl = row[1:9]
        break

    df = pd.read_csv(argv[1],header=0)
    df = [df[col].tolist() for col in df.columns]
```

ignore the strl part its for something else unrelated

but it outputs like this:

```
[['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [2, 4, 3], [8, 1, 2], [3, 5, 5]]
```

i want it to output like this:

```
[['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [2, 8, 3], [4, 1, 5], [3, 2, 5]]
```

i would like it to output like the above  sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pandas

```
In [13]: import pandas as pd

In [14]: df = pd.read_csv("a.csv",header=None)

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
         0  1  2  3
0    Alice  2  8  3
1      Bob  4  1  5
2  Charlie  3  2  5

In [16]: [df[col].tolist() for col in df.columns]
Out[16]: [['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [2, 4, 3], [8, 1, 2], [3, 5, 5]]
```

Update:

```
In [51]: import pandas as pd

In [52]: df = pd.read_csv("a.csv",header=None)

In [53]: data = df[df.columns[1:]].to_numpy().tolist()

In [57]: data.insert(0,df[0].tolist())

In [58]: data
Out[58]: [['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [2, 8, 3], [4, 1, 5], [3, 2, 5]]
```

Update:

```
In [51]: import pandas as pd

In [52]: df = pd.read_csv("a.csv")

In [94]: df
Out[94]:
      name  AGATC  AATG  TATC
0    Alice      2     8     3
1      Bob      4     1     5
2  Charlie      3     2     5

In [97]: data = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'name'].to_numpy().tolist()

In [98]: data.insert(0, df["name"].tolist())

In [99]: data
Out[99]: [['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [2, 8, 3], [4, 1, 5], [3, 2, 5]]
```

Comment: I'm so sorry i wrote the wrong result i wanted the opposite  i updated my  original post if you could help me with that one , Thanks for your help

Comment: @Yoda Can you let me know the final result you need? There are 2 results you have given

Comment: i changed header to None and it worked but the file has one line at top that i don't want it in my list (Name,Number,Value) , i changed header to 1 and doesnt work

Comment: :) accpeted , thanks you for your effort and time . i wish i could upvote but i dont have enough rep yet